# How can a player in ALO make an original Sword Skill?

Tags: sword-art-online

I know the fact that Kirito's Dual Wield in SAO was an award or was awarded by the system for being the top player with the fastest reaction time. see [here](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Dual_Blades)

And that Yuuki can pass down her insane sword combo - 11 hit (Mother's Rosario) to other players like Asuna. (Because kirito is having a hard time reproducing Starburst Stream in ALO which is 16 hit combo, as stated [here](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Dual_Blades))

But how did Konno Yuuki create this skill? Or is it just a skill which came from her converted account because she was in some other VRMMO?

Is there a chapter in the light novel / manga where this is discussed?

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere that Kirito's Skill Connect is awarded by the system, and for people with fastest reaction time?

Comment: Sorry edited my question, skill connect is not awarded by the system it is a skill developed through a players capability which requires excellent timing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wiki page has an explanation on this:

> To record a new OSS, the player needs to open the menu, move to the OSS panel and activate the Sword Skill recording mode by pressing "Start" there. After that, the player only needs to swing one's weapon in a desired set of moves and press "Finish" once done. The downside of this system is that such skills are only accepted by the system if they meet very high speed, combo and execution requirements. To create an OSS the player must be able to execute the skill flawlessly, at the same speed as the completed skill but unassisted by the system. This should be impossible without the system's assist, but players have managed to create various OSSs.
>
> Besides adding the ability to automatically use desired moves, it also adds elemental damage, which can be from fire, earth, lightning, water, light and darkness, to the Sword Skill. A skill can have up to two different elemental attributes and the damage rate of the skill is a combined percentage between the physical damage and the magical damage.

http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Original_Sword_Skill